# How to create random number between given range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, css-grid

I have the following problem:

Given is an 8-column grid. Now I want to place an item randomly inside it with a random span-width. I figured it out, how to place it randomly and give it a random width.
But I can't figure out, how to adjust the width based on parameters.

So for example:
columnStart and columnSpan should be less or equal than 8 but still number 2 should be at least 2.

So columnStart can max only be 6.

Thank you for the help!

I tried it with this:
`let columnStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1; let columnSpan = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 2;`

Which resulted in objects, starting at columnStart 6 and span over 6 more columns. Which shouldn't be due it's only a 8-column grid.

I also tried a do-while loop:
`do { let columnStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1; let columnSpan = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 2; } while (columnStart + columnSpan === 8)`

But this also didn't brought the result I tried to achieve

Comment: *So columnStart can max only be 6* - is that zero-based?  Otherwise max columnStart would be 7.

Comment: Determine the `columnSpan` first, then change the `columnStart` to be max `(8-(columnSpan-1))`   Alternatively:  do your calc then `if ((columnStart + columnSpan) > 8) columnStart = columnSpan - columnStart` - though that would trend to have most of the columns right-aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// 1 to 6.
const columnStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
// 2 to 8
const columnSpan = 2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (8 - columnStart));
console.log("Start:", columnStart, "Span:", columnSpan);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  // Generate a random number between 0 and 1 (exclusive)
  const randomFraction = Math.random();
  
  // Scale the random number to the desired range (max - min) and shift it by min
  const randomNumberInRange = randomFraction * (max - min) + min;

  // Use Math.floor or Math.round to get an integer result, if needed
  return Math.floor(randomNumberInRange); // Change to Math.round for rounding
}

// Example usage:
const minNumber = 1;
const maxNumber = 100;
const randomNum = getRandomNumber(minNumber, maxNumber);
console.log(randomNum);
```